# Convert integers to floats in awk

Tags: bash, awk, floating-point, integer

```
cat file.txt
1
1.6
0
0.7
2
3
3.7
```

The expected output is:

```
1.0
1.6
0.0
0.7
2.0
3.0
3.7
```

any awk or bash solution? Wherever is integer, convert to float.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To `awk`, it is just a matter to indicate the format you want to use to print the results. Use [`printf`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Format-Modifiers) to indicate that you want 1 decimal digit:

```
$ awk '{printf ("%.1f\n", $1)}' file
1.0
1.6
0.0
0.7
2.0
3.0
3.7
```

You can say `%e` for scientific format, `%.5f` to get 5 digits, etc. See the provided link for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Similarly to the solution with `awk`, you can use `printf` with bash too, e.g. via [xargs](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?xargs):

```
cat file.txt | xargs -n 1 printf "%.1f\n"
```

The formatting options of printf are [similar](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/printf).

Note that printf (either for awk or bash) will output rounded value. So if you have `0.77` in your input, the result of the `%.1f` format will be `0.8`.